# Fill t-shirt with color and change text color accordingly on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've drawn out a t-shirt on canvas and I am currently trying to fill it when the user selects a colour on the menu above. In addition, I'd like the text on the t-shirt to change accordingly (for instance if the color black is selected then the t-shirt text color should be white). Is this possible?

Snippet of the code so far:

```
<body>T-shirt color
    <br>
    <canvas id="toolsCanvas" width=300 height=53></canvas>
    <br>
    <p>
        <canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="520" height="0"></canvas>
        <canvas id="itemCanvas" width="520" height="429"></canvas>
</body>
```

It would be easier to demonstrate what I'm speaking it, jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rtnq8mjL/

Comment: Yes, should be possible.  You've got the basic idea down already: just do a `ctx.fill()` in response to the color selection event.  Looks like you will need to define a closed region for the body of the shirt (the arms, collar, etc. are all closed, but the button doesn't appear to be).

Comment: I am able to fill it using `ctx.fill()`.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtnq8mjL/1/). You should fill for each close path.. I implemented a `setColor()` function..  check that for understanding.

Comment: Been playing around with it, but you're basically missing the center part as your lines don't really close in that part.

Comment: @adeneo - any idea why this happening?

Comment: It's happening because the lines don't close the shirt properly, I got this far -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rtnq8mjL/4/**, but I need a second to trace the lines.

Comment: @adeneo - should I go back to the drawing board on this one?

Comment: You just have to draw the center part, I started but you can finish it yourself with the beziercurves etc -> http://jsfiddle.net/rtnq8mjL/5/

Comment: When you say centre part - what do you mean?

Comment: @methuselah it means the part which was not being colored before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ctx.fillStyle = color` and `ctx.fill()` methods to fill that shirt. but somehow the shirt is not being filled with color completely.

Here is the [partially completed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtnq8mjL/3/).

I hope you can solve this from here.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track, I think @adeneo is having a look at why the shirt does not fill completely