# T-shirt on HTML5 canvas won't completely fill

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The t-shirt I have drawn on the HTML5 canvas won't completely fill, and I think that it is down to a bezier curve missing. Could anyone help me identify where, as I'd like to get the entire t-shirt filled and I'm struggling to figure out how.

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="toolsCanvas" width=300 height=53></canvas>
<canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="520" height="429"></canvas>
```

Live demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/rtnq8mjL/6/

Comment: Previous question, for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613533/fill-t-shirt-with-color-and-change-text-color-accordingly-on-html-canvas

Comment: I removed from fiddle step by step all your curves and basically you missed to fill (and so draw) exactly the part that remains white... it's white because it's the background of the canvas

Comment: yes it was just a fill missing http://jsfiddle.net/62a02vmL/